# Joomla ajax upload not receiving file

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, joomla

I'm uploading file with ajax like this:

```
var data = new FormData();
    jQuery.each(files, function(key, value)
    {
        data.append(key, value);
    });
    jQuery.ajax({
        url: "<?php echo JURI::base().'modules/xxx/ajax_upload.php' ?>",
        type: 'POST',
        data: data,
        cache: false,
        dataType: 'json',
        processData: false, // Don't process the files
        contentType: false, // Set content type to false as jQuery will tell the server its a query string request
        success: function(data)
        {
            if(typeof data.error === 'undefined')
        {
            // Success so call function to process the form
            //submitForm(event, data);
        }
        else
        {
            // Handle errors here
            console.log('ERRORS: ' + data.error);
        }
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
        {
            // Handle errors here
            console.log('ERRORS: ' + textStatus);
            // STOP LOADING SPINNER
        }
    });
```

In console I see that the image is sent, but in ajax_upload.php I can't get file, trying with:

```
print_r($_FILES);
print_r($_POST);
```

and it returns empty array, form has `enctype="multipart/form-data"`

Comment: Are you making full use of the com_ajax component that comes packed with Joomla 3.2? If you're using Joomla 1.5, 2.5 or 3.1, then you can download it from github and install it. It will make integrating Ajax with your module much easier. https://github.com/Joomla-Ajax-Interface/component

Comment: you should use $_FILES and not $_FILE (maybe it's only a writing error...)

Comment: my bad, I used $_FILES, but wrongly typed here

Comment: @AlbertoFecchi -  No, you shouldn't use `$_FILES`. This is Joomla, which uses different coding standards to raw PHP or other frameworks/CMS's. Please refer to the documentation

Comment: any help how to do it?